# should my website be the product or the name of my business(we switched to selling just one product)

Tags: website-design, design

We recently did away with "other products" and we now specialize in just tabcoupon booklets(for fundraising) and my belief is that we should just simplify it to its essence and do away with the business name(Westmoreland Fund Raising) and just focus on the [tabcoupon.com](http://tabcoupon.com) part.

Can anyone take a look and tell me what they think?(I would be open to any other pieces of advice also)

Thanks

Comment: This is more a marketing than a user experience question. A marketing.stackexchange.com is not yet in existence, but there is an area 51 proposal for it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51786/marketing which you may be interested in.

Comment: This would make an excellent example question there, in my opinion.

Comment: Ask RIM... err... [Blackberry](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/01/30/us-rim-blackberry-name-idUSBRE90T0XU20130130).

Comment: What happens if the business changes again? Would this problem have been avoided if you took the other approach in the first place? Ultimately it is a choice between designing for change or changing your designs, and it needs to fit with the overall business plan/strategy.

Answer (score 1):

This question is definitely more related to marketing. From UX point of view the main question which you need to ask yourself - who is your customer. Or in other words, is your business B2C or B2B? If your business is B2C, your user expects to work with a product or service and rearely care about company name or company at all. If your business is B2B, your user expects to see more details about company and business terms. In general, you may need to have 2 websites - product/service site for end-users and corporate site for corporate clients/partners. In any case corporate site should exist to bring flexibility to business and make it independent from its product(s). Of course, unless it is not strong brand.

Answer (score 1):

Why not both? I would recommend having the product push people to the company site - this will reinforce the company brand, which is generally more valuable than the product brand.

For user experience, the goal is to allow the user to find you. If they are more familiar with the product, having the product as a url good and worth the small added expence.